# Wine menubuilder.exe crash

Tags: macos, wine

I am trying to install Steam with Wineskin but I get a window showing "winemenubuilder.exe has encountered a serious problem" the log of this crash is [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2uWjQ0a5)

---

I am using OS X Mavericks (10.9.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you did exactly this step by step:

1. Create a new blank wrapper with the latest Wine Engine
2. Select Install software and click SteamSetup.exe in Downloads or wherever you put it
3. Go through the setup wizard.
4. This is where the crash takes place. Force Quit all Wineskin processes.
5. Launch your wrapper again and click Advanced options
6. In the EXE flags, type `-no-dwrite`, tick use Start.exe and change nothing.exe on top to `C:\Program Files\Steam\Steam.exe`
7. Now do a test run and see if it worked. Now whenever you launch your wrapper, Steam should launch.